# Returning local values from Bash variables?

Tags: bash, shell, variable, function, command-substitution

I studied this article called [Returning Values from Bash Functions](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions).
Data

```
Lorem.
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

### Case #1 which does not work

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
function getStart {
        local START="$(awk '/begin\{document\}/{ print NR; exit }' data.tex)"
}

START2=$(getStart)
echo $START2
```

which returns falsely an empty line. 
I expect `1`. 
**Why does the script return an empty line?**

### Case #2 which works

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
function getStart {
        local START="$(awk '/begin\{document\}/{ print NR; exit }' data.tex)"
        echo $START
}

getStart
```

which prints correctly `1`.

### Output of choroba's answer

```
#!/bin/bash
function getStart {
        local START="$(awk '/begin\{document\}/{ print NR; exit }' data.tex)"
        echo $START
}

START2=$(getStart)
echo $START2
```

gives the linenumber only once, which is not the expected result. 
I think it should do it twice.

Comment: Regarding your update, see my edit to the answer, but in general, don't expect people to answer updates to questions. Comment on the answer if you think it isn't clear, or ask a new question.

Comment: The whole point of command substitution is that the outputs doesn't go out, but gets captured in a variable instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(...)` (aka "Command substitution") captures the output of the `...` command. Assigning a value to a variable produces no output, so there's nothing to capture. In case #2, `echo` produces the output.

```
getStart () {
    local l=Hallo
    echo $l
}

v=$(getStart)
echo $v
```

To answer your update: the function outputs `Hallo`. This output is captured by the command substitution, because that's what command substitution does, so up to `v=$(getStart)`, the script produces no output. Then the line `echo $v` outputs `Hallo`.

Comment: Can you given an example how you would get the expected result with the case #1?

Comment: @Masi: You have to output the value, otherwise it gets lost when the function is left.

Comment: @Masi: `function` is optional. The output of the first echo is consumed by the `$(...)`, so you see only the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the awk command in it and forget about capturing. Functions can echo something and additionally, they do return an exit status. If you don't explicitly return (e.g., `return 1`), the exit status of a function will be the exit status of the last command.
That's why you probably don't want to capture + echo in the function. It would shadow the exit status of the captured command with the exit status of echo (0, barring unusual circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple function to remove `local`-ness from a variable via `unset`+`set`:

```
function return_local()
{
  unset $1 # must be local
  eval "$1=\"\$2\""
}
```

We have to use `eval` instead of `declare` because it does create a variable either local or exported, when we need to create a not local not exported variable.

```
function test()
{
  local my_return_value=123
  # ...
  return_local my_return_value "$my_return_value"
}
```

The `unset` instruction removes a most inner `local` variable, so you have to write `return_local` in each function which wants to return a local variable. So `return_local` can be used in nested call contexts.

And no need to use `$(...)` operator as long as it creates separate process which is cost a performance in bash under Windows because a process create is not cheap there.